# Special ink for iPhone (or other mobile) screen for interaction

Tags: android, ios

Last night I was playing Monopoly Zapped with the kids and I because quite intrigued as to how it worked. Basically, you interact with a tablet (or phone) whenever you want to do something... buy property, get out of jail, etc.

The weird thing is it all works just by touching the card to the screen (not the camera and there is no chip in the card) and the device does all the work... it even knows if a player is using the wrong card.

I've done a lot of searching on the Internet and cannot find ANYTHING to describe how this works. The only think I can think is there is some sort of "electrified" ink that is reacting with the digitizer on the screen.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [app developer's website](http://thegameagency.com/index.php/portfolio-posts/monopoly-zapped_draft/), the cards use [conductive ink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductive_ink) which can interact with the mobile device's capacitive screen.

[image: Monopoly Zapped]